# Batch AVI encoding (xVid/mp3)

Tags: video, batch, compression, xvid

I'm looking for some way to batch-encode Uncompressed AVI (with PCM audio) videos recorded with my digital camera.

I've been using VirtualDub, but I can't find an automated/batch way to do it.

I basically want something I can select a folder or group of files (.avi) and automatically applies xvid and maybe mp3 compression also.

Any ideas? Freeware apps or command line tools are ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/):

> WinFF is a GUI for the command line
>   video converter, FFMPEG. It will
>   convert most any video file that
>   FFmpeg will convert. WinFF does
>   multiple files in multiple formats at
>   one time. You can for example convert
>   mpeg's, flv's, and mov's, all into
>   avi's all at once. WinFF is available
>   for Windows 95, 98 , ME, NT, XP,
>   VISTA, and Debian, Ubuntu, Redhat
>   based GNU/Linux distributions.